# "Write the name in the top line and below the address"

Tags: meaning

During the application process on "uni-assist" site, there was a phrase:

> The signed application and all required paper documents must reach uni-assist by the end of the application deadline. Write the name of the university you are applying for in the top line and below the address:
>
> uni-assist e.V.
>   11507 Berlin
>   GERMANY

So, does that mean that they literally want me to do something like this?

> TUM
>   uni-assist e.V.
>   11507 Berlin
>   GERMANY
>   TUM

P.S. I asked uni-assist too, but their response time is 2-3 days.

Comment: It is a strange requirement, but I think that your interpretation is correct.

Comment: What is the answer from uni-assist ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, the mail was delivered with the following data on it

> TUM
>   uni-assist e.V.
>   11507 Berlin
>   GERMANY
>   TUM

I still don't know whether it's the correct way or not, but it got things delivered in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

No. You should write the name of the university above the address provided, not below it.  A clearer rewrite of the requirement would be:

> Write the name of the university you are applying for **on** the top line and below **it write** the **following** address:

The address will allow the post office to direct the letter correctly, and the top line will tell uni-assist which university you are interested in.  The university name is an internal mailbox at this address, in other words.

Write the following:

```
TUM
uni-assist e.V.
11507 Berlin
GERMANY
```